# Should I use async/await in Vuex store actions?

Tags: vuex

Is it a good practice to use `async`/`await` in Vuex store actions with Nuxt or is it useless and why ?

```
export const actions = {
  async getFoo({ state, commit }) {
    await this.$axios.get('api/foo').then((res) => {
      commit('FOO_SETUP', res.data)
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use them as you please, that's the whole point of actions (vs mutations, who MUST be synchronous)

You can also await them

```js
await dispatch('getFoo')
```